# How do you completely shut down Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I'm using Hughesnet for internet and I have a daily 200 mb limit on downloads. How can I exit Ubuntu One and be sure that I'm no longer syncing or downloading anything. I have unlimited downloads between 1 am and 6 am cst, I only want to sync or download during these hours.

I have Ubuntu 11.04 on Virtualbox on a Windows 7 host, and have Ubuntu one on both systems. I've used windows task manager to end 2 obvious Ubuntu One processes, is this sufficient? Are there any more processes to shut off or can I just exit on the system tray context menu?

Comment: "We are sorry to notify you that we will be shutting down the Ubuntu One file services, effective 1 June 2014".  Seems like Canonical figured out how to shut down Ubuntu One for you.  :)

Answer (score 2):

run `gnome-session-properties` and uncheck the "Ubuntu One" service.

You can also set transfer limits in `ubuntuone-preferences`.

Answer (score 1):

Open Ubuntu One and

1) Click Disconnect. It gets renamed to Connect. Only click Connect after 1am .

2) Select the services tab and uncheck the box Enable File Sync. Only enable file sync when you want to update.

3) Do not mark folders for syncing with Ubuntu One that contain documents that are being edited. Then these documents will not be synchronized out of hours. Use Copy and Paste to put documents in the Ubuntu One folder when you want the document to be updated on the Ubuntu One cloud storage.